# Projectreactor: the parallel execution of queries and concatenating the results

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Good evening.
I am studying reactive programming and I have encountered the following problem.

I am running two parallel queries to the database and want to combine the results and give them back

```
    @GetMapping
    public Mono<User> get(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("cId") String cId) {
        Mono<User> userMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> userServ.get(id))
                .flatMap(userMono1 -> userMono1)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

        Mono<Comment> ger = Mono.fromCallable(() -> commentServ.ger(cId))
                .flatMap(commentMono -> commentMono)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());


        return Mono.zip(userMono, ger)
                .map(pair -> {
                    User t1 = pair.getT1();
                    t1.setComment(pair.getT2());
                    return t1;
                });
```

But the point is that the comment may be empty, and then I expect to return the json of such a structure

```
{
    "id": "5e6cbf395214a42f51b57121",
    "name": "Bob",
    "surname": null,
    "comment": null
}
```

Instead I get an empty response. Apparently this is due to mono zip, but how else can I combine the results, while maintaining query parallelism

My entities:

```
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Comment {
    @Id
    String id;
    String userId;
    String comment;
}

@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Comment comment;
}
```

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zip/ZipWith` need elements to produce their output. If it could be empty , you could use below methods to set some default value.

- `defaultIfEmpty(new Comment())` or
- `switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> new Comment())`

If you do not want to use `new Comment()` and set `null` to comment object, we can try this way.

```
        userMono
                .zipWith(commentMono.defaultIfEmpty(new Comment()))
                .map(pair -> {
                    User user = pair.getT1();
                    Comment comment = pair.getT2();
                    if(Objects.nonNull(comment.getUserId()))
                       user.setComment(comment);
                    return user;
                 });
```

Comment: this is also a prime case for `Optional`, I think